# How do I install AMD Radeon HD 7570M/Intel Hybrid drivers?

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, fglrx, hybrid-graphics, amd-graphics

My system is overheating frequently, and sometimes it shuts down, so I think I have to install the AMD/Intel Hybrid drivers to fix this problem... My laptop is [this Dell with Intel/AMD Hybrid Graphics](http://www.dell.com/us/p/inspiron-14z-5423/pd) and I am running Xubuntu 16.04 amd64 (I made a zero installation today).

```
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7550M/7570M/7650M] [1002:6841] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

This is what I have tried:

1. Installing drivers with `sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-dev` -- didn't work.
2. Installing drivers with .deb packages from [AMD Website](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/previous/detail?os=Ubuntu%20x86%2064&rev=15.9) -- didn't work.
3. Following the instructions here and here -- didn't work.

Now I am trying to install the drivers manually, as described [here (section 4.2)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD#Manually_installing_Catalyst_13.4.2C_special_case_for_Intel.2FAMD_hybrid_graphics) and in [this guide (sections 2.3 to 2.3.2)](http://www2.ati.com/relnotes/amd-catalyst-graphics-driver-installer-notes-for-linux-operating-systems.pdf) using [this driver](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/previous/detail?os=Linux%20x86_64&rev=15.9) that I have downloaded from AMD Website.

When I try to run the .run file as root, this error message appears:

```
ERROR: Please install the required pre-requisites before proceeding with AMD Catalyst installation. Please check file usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log for more details
```

I have checked the `/usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log` and the content is:

```
NOTE: If your system has logged the missing packages required for installation, install them in the order as per the log file to resolve package-dependency issues.

fglrx installation requires that the system has kernel headers.  /lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.
Install kernel headers using the command apt-get install linux-headers-4.4.0-22-generic.
```

So I ran `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.4.0-22-generic` and:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-4.4.0-22-generic is already the newest version (4.4.0-22.39).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: AMD does not support the new Xorg's. Are you on 16.04? Then they force you to use the open drivers. Please contribute to their development! :) For more infos, [read the release notes of 16.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes#Graphics_and_Display).

Comment: It will be a pleasure to contribute! Thank you for the information. But, for now, what do you recommend me? A downgrade do 14.04 will work fine with my system?

Comment: Yes, it will probably work fine.

Comment: I've installed Xubuntu 14.04.4 LTS amd64 and the drivers are working fine, now. Thank you very much! Now I'm going to learn how to contribute to open drivers development :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. Either downgrade to 14.04 or install open source AMDGPU/ATI drivers.

This is how I installed AMD drivers in my Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial

Download the AMDGPU-PRO from [here](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx)

Run the following commands in the terminal

`tar xvzf amdgpu-pro-16.40-XXXXXX.tar.xz`

`cd amdgpu-pro-16.40-XXXXXX`

`chmod +x amdgpu-pro-install`

`sudo ./amdgpu-pro-install`

Replace XXXXXX with the build number. Finally issue the following obvious command.

`sudo reboot`

To verify if it installed successfully issue `dpkg -l amdgpu-pro`

Source: https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx